# array public usable en all model, controler and views.. its posible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to fill an array of a search result that their information can be accessed from any model, controller or view. is it possible?

```
module AdsHelper
attr_reader :table

def initialize
    @table = []
end

 def add_ads_table(ads)
     ads.each do |ad|
        @table << ad
     end
 end
end
```

@table is the "public" array

```
class AdsController < ApplicationController
attr_reader :tabla
include AdsHelper

  def index
    order = sortable_column_order
    if params[:search]
       @ads = Ad.search(params[:search], params[:page],params[:sort])
       add_ads_table(@ads)
    else
        @ads = Ad.paginate(:per_page => 4, :page => params[:page], :order => order)
        add_ads_table(@ads)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @ads }
    end
  end
end
```

after completing the array I want to show the information in a view of the same model Ad

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for a global variable to me. Just start your variable declaration with an $ instead of @, like this:

```
def initialize
    $table = []
end
```

Use with care! Globals litering code can end up making a pretty impressive mess of things, not to mention end up with weird scenarios about them. Just a warning.

Comment: maybe if it's that way, but I think my problem is that the array is not full and do not understand why. My sitaxis is correct?
change the declaration of the array with $ and now I see the light but without errors.

Comment: Hmm. Looking more closely at your code, it looks like there may be some other things awry. You don't need to have the attr_reader :tabla (table?) in the class itself, because the item is being set globally. Trying to gauge your intent... are you trying to have this variable on a per request basis, on a per application basis?

Comment: I really need to do is make a search after the same result I need to see another view in another format, without losing the values ​​of search. And I thought it passing the result of that search to another array to display the same result in another format design

Comment: So it needs to exist across requests, but not long term? You may want to think about using a session variable for that instead, rather than making it global. On your rails controller, the session is just available to you. So you could use something like.. "session[:table]" to see if it's there, and error if it's not. Or something like that. Might be a little less error prone.

Comment: is correct it would not be long term, it would be a possible solution using sessions but not how, I'm new to this language. tnks